# How to prevent non-root users from login into the system using nologin shell with ansible?

Tags: ansible

Is there a better way to do the following using a different ansible module?

```
- name: prevent non-root users from login into the system using nologin shell
  command: usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin consul
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the built in module which is idempotent (the command call is not):

```
- name: prevent non-root users from login into the system using nologin shell
  user: 
    name: consul
    shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
```